# Pagination control outside datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am generating a datable with standard options, but I want to move the pagination control to another `<div>` outside sDom like

```
<div class="pagination">pagination</div>
```

So far I found how to copy it looks like:

```
"fnInitComplete": function(oSettings){
    var $pagination = $('.dataTables_paginate').clone(true, true);
    $('.navbar-inner').append($pagination);
}
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure - [here's your solution](http://liveweave.com/83z5uj)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#example").dataTable();
 //$("#NewPaginationContainer").append($(".dataTables_paginate").clone(true));
  $("#NewPaginationContainer").append($(".dataTables_paginate"));
} );
```